# Adding objects with different parameter into the array

Tags: java, arrays

So I have this question,

**Class circle:**

1. Contains an appropriate attribute to store the radius.
2. Contains a constructor with one parameter to set the radius.
3. Contains set and get methods.
4. Contains a method for calculating the area and another method for calculating the
   circumference.
5. Circle should contain an appropriate attribute to keep track (count) of the number of
   Circle objects instantiated.

**Class TestCircle:**

Create an array of 10 circles of radii 1.0 , 2.0, ..., 10.0.

Print the area and circumference of each circle.

Retrieve and print the number of circles that have been instantiated.

**My code is:**

```
public class Circle {   
  public double radius= 0.0;
  public int counter;
  public Circle (double radius){
    this.radius = radius;
    counter++;
  }
  public Circle (){
  }

  public void setRadius (double radius){
    this.radius = radius;
  }
  public double getRadius (){
    return radius;
  }
  public double Area (){
    return 3.14*radius*radius;
  }
  public double Circumference (){
    return 2*3.14*radius;
  }
}


public class TestCircle {
  public static void main (String args []){
    Circle [] arr = new Circle [10];
    System.out.println ("The circumference" + arr.Circumference());
    System.out.println ("The area" + arr.Area());
    System.out.println ("The number of circles" + arr.counter);
  }
}
```

**My question is:**
How am I supposed to create 10 circle objects with different radius and add it to the array?
I know that the idea was to add the objects to the array by using the for loop but I couldn't add the radius into the process.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the for-loop? And `counter` needs to be static.

Comment: You might consider making a constant `pi` or else finding a system built-in in place of the magic numbers in your code.

Comment: The for loop I had in mind was something like this: for (int i =0; i<10; i++)
arr [i] = new Circle ();

Comment: You mean by importing the Math package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could change like

```
public class Circle {   
    private double radius;
    private static int numberOfCircles = 0;
    public Circle (double radius){
      this.radius = radius;
      numberOfCircles++;
      System.out.println("The circumference : " + getCircumference());
      System.out.println("The area : " + getArea());
    }

    public double getRadius (){
      return radius;
    }
    public double getArea (){
      return 3.14*radius*radius;
    }
    public double getCircumference (){
      return 2*3.14*radius;
    }

    public static int getNumberOfCirclesCreated(){
       return numberOfCircles;
    }
}


public class TestCircle {
  public static void main (String args []) {
      Circle [] circles = new Circle [10];
      for(int counter=0;counter< circles.length;counter++){
         circles[counter]=new Circle((double)(counter+1));
      }
      System.out.println("Number of circles : " + Circle.getNumberOfCirclesCreated());
   }
}
```

Comment: Where is the part that the `Circle` class keeps track of how many have been created?

Comment: Where did he/she say that it needs to do that ? Never the less will add that code change ...

Comment: My bad didn't ready that one correctly. There is still some code change required will do that.

Comment: They did not teach us anything about lists yet so I'm not allowed to use them. I'm sorry for wasting your effort and thank you.

Comment: "for(int counter=1;counter<11;counter++)" - I know people who would bitch-slap you for this!

Comment: @Fildor Please explain why ?

Comment: That does make sense since they are slightly similar, thanks again.

Comment: You give the reason yourself: `circles[counter]=(new Circle((double)counter));` - this will fail with OutOfBounds! Java Arrays start at index 0! Your loop's last iteration will have `counter=10` but circles's valid indices are from 0 to 9.

Comment: Dam how did i miss that ... Stupid me ... thinking of complicated things the simple ones are forgotten ...

Answer (score 0):

Create for loop that iterates through each array cell. You then create a new `Circle` object and call its `setRadius` function. You then set array Cell to equal the `Circle` object and continue iterating till the array is filled.

Additionally, your counter should be static (as corrected by Fildor). Consider also setting `radius` as private, seeing as you put in getter/setters.

Comment: This: "Circle should contain an appropriate attribute to keep track (count) of the number of Circle objects instantiated" clearly states, that `counter` should be a static member of `Circle`.

Comment: I just reread that. You are correct, it just seems weird to store the counter in Circle, but the requirements do say so I guess.

Comment: Why do you think it is weird? The count of Circle Objects is an attribute of the Circle class, so it should be kept there. That's what data encapsulation is all about ... Different thing would be if we would have to keep track of count of Circles instantiated by TestCircle's main method ...

Comment: It roughly looks like this: Circle arr [] = new Circle [10];
Circle c1 = new Circle ();
for (int i =0; i<10; i++){
c1.setRadius();
arr[i]= c1;
}

Comment: "2. Contains a **constructor** with one parameter to set the radius."

Comment: Oh yes I actually did that before but then the compiler went crazy so I temporarily made it public. Am I supposed to initialize that radius inside the constructor?

Comment: @Boshokai Requirement 2. sais so.